# Move down on Sub menu

Tags: html, menu, scroll

I have a menu which has two sub menus.  On the 3rd sub menu there is 12 options, but only 6 appear on my page.  They stop at my the start of my next content wrapper.   I have been searching but I can only find scroll bars, which is not what I want.  I want it to scroll down when the user clicks on an arrow.  Any help would be great, I am pretty new to creating websites.

```
<div id="mainContent">
   <div class="contentWrapper">
      <div id="column-vertical-LS">
          <div id="column-side1">
<h1> Studyspace Courses</h1>
<p>Click on a course to learn how to use.  </p>
  <div id='cssmenu'>
   <ul>
   <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Study Start-up</span></a>

      <ul> <li class='has-sub2'><a href='#'><span>Publisher</span></a> <ul>
             <li><a href='#'><span>Clinical Trial Introduction</span></a></li>
             <li><a href='#'><span>Clinical Trial Login</span></a></li>
             <li><a href='#'><span>Clinical Trial Navigating the Hub</span></a></li>
             <li><a href='#'><span>Clinical Trial Navigating the Exchange</span></a></li>
             <li><a href='#'><span>Clinical Trial Viewing Documents</span></a></li>
             <li><a href='#'><span>Clinical Trial Downloading Docs</span></a></li>
             <li><a href='#'><span>Clinical Trial Printing</span></a></li>
             <li><a href='#'><span>Clinical Trial Tasks</span></a></li>
             <li><a href='#'><span>Submitting by Fax</span></a></li>
             <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Clinical Trial Key Contacts</span></a></li>
      </ul> </li>
           </div>
             </div>
                 </div>
                   </div>
                       </div>
```

Comment: I think we're going to need your CSS also.  Can you make a jsfiddle? (jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Little weird to close your divs out, off to the right like that...